# Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.5

Tags: maven

When I import a maven program by Spring Tool Suite,a problem occurs:
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.5 from http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-roo-repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.5 from/to spring-roo-repository: connection timed out to http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.pom.
I want to know how to resolve it. If you know,please tell me.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing failed downloads.

try this...

```
cd %username%\.m2\repository
for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i
```

For linux.

```
find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer" {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;
```

After that right click on project and update maven dependency.